# Gmail unsubscribe link shows 'undefined', though link is correct

Tags: gmail, mailing-list, unsubscribe

In Gmail when you have an email from a newslist, you get a 'unsubscribe' link next to the email address, like this:

Google+ <noreply-67e4f7ae@plus.google.com> Unsubscribe

If you click it, it says:

> Unsubscribe from **Google+** 
>   **Google+** provides a page at **plus.google.com**
>   where you can manage your email subscriptions. Learn more

Okay, when I send newsletters, I get the following message with 'undefined' instead, note that the link is actually right, it's just the text label that's wrong:

> Unsubscribe from newslist@mywebsite.com 
>   **Sender** provides a page at
>   **undefined** where you can manage your email subscriptions. Learn more

I'm sending the following header:

```
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe-request@mywebsite.com?subject=Unsubscribe+my+newsletter>,
<http://www.mywebsite.com/instant_unsubscribe.php?id=111&email=myemail@mywebsite.com>
```

Any ideas how I stop is saying '**undefined**' and change 'sender' to my website?

Thanks!